# android zoom control

Tags: android

i want to put a zoom control button in my android application just like map view where we can zoom in and zoom out the whole view ,but its not a mapview .
Plz help me .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
websettings = objectview.getSettings();
websettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: WebView objectview;                                                             WebSettings websettings;